# Using trigger to automatically update field when inserting a new row

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert

I have this table `Studentinformation`
 I want to create a trigger so that whenever a new row is inserted, without the `Email` column specified, the trigger will fire and automatically update the `Email` column. The email format will look like this `FirstName`.`LastName`@youremail.com
 
 For example: ('John', 'Smith')
 This would look like: JohnSmith@youremail.com
However, if the insert statement already contains an email address, the trigger will not update the email field.
 
Can someone help me write or modify the query I have so far?
`Studentinformation` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Studentinformation (
                    StudentID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(100,1) PRIMARY KEY,
                    Title char(10) NULL,
                    FirstName char(10) NULL,
                    LastName char(10) NULL,
                    Address1 char(50) NULL,
                    Address2 char(50) NULL,
                    City char(50) NULL,
                    County char(50) NULL,
                    Zip char(10) NULL,
                    Country char(50) NULL,
                    Telephone char(10) NULL,
                    Email varchar(255) NULL,
                    Enrolled char(10) NULL,
                    AltTelephone char(10) NULL);
```

What I have so far:

```
-- This code creates a trigger
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_assignEmail;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_assignEmail ON Studentinformation
FOR INSERT
AS
UPDATE Studentinformation
SET Email = FirstName+'.'+LastName+'@youremail.com'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I highly recommend reading the official documentation on triggers, specifically about using the Inserted and Deleted tables, since you will most likely want to constrain your update to only those rows modified. You will also want to add as part of your where clause a check to see that the email column is null or empty, else you will overwrite existing email addresses.

Comment: What is the problem? your trigger look fine except not checking if email is specified which can be done with an IF expression.

Comment: @MeyssamToluie Exactly that, I'm not sure how to write the next part/clause that'll check to see that the email column is null or empty

Comment: @DaleK Can you show me what the clause would look like to check if the email column is null or empty?

Comment: If you aren't familiar with writing a where clause I strongly suggest checking out a few tutorials. If someone gives you an answer here you're not going to have learnt anything, just been given an answer. Then the next time you run into an issue you're doing to need to ask again. Do the learning... take some tutorials...

Comment: @Meyssam Toluie - "your trigger look fine" - Nope. It's not batch safe.

Comment: I can't see the point of deliberately storing an incorrect email - it just makes it harder to find them especially if names change and for email shots you might be firing them into the great nowhere.

Comment: Every "real" column nullable? Just start over. Relational database design is a skill that must be learned. It does not magically become part of your consciousness by learning basic tsql. _JohnSmith@youremail.com_ But your logic includes a period to separate the names. Which is your actual goal?

Answer (score 1):

The basic statement you need is as follows. Using the *inserted* table which contains only the row(s) inserted for the current server process, join back to the table on its primary key and update only the inserted rows which are not blank (and implied also not NULL).

```
update s 
  set s.email = Concat(s.FirstName, '.', s.LastName, '@youremail.com')
from inserted i 
join Studentinformation s on s.StudentId = i.StudentId 
where i.email != '';
```

Comment: Op wanted email updated only if the insert *didn't* contain van email address. You appear to update when it does?

Answer (score 0):

I complete the answer with `ISNULL` function.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_assignEmail ON Studentinformation
After INSERT
AS  
    UPDATE s
      SET Email = Isnull(i.Email, Concat(i.FirstName, '.', i.LastName,'@youremail.com'))
    FROM inserted i JOIN Studentinformation s on s.StudentId = i.StudentId
```

Comment: Missing inserted table reference